# Why is the userIdentity property always empty in AWS’ Kinesis DataStream?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have enabled Kinesis DataStream in DynamoDB and have configured a Delivery Stream to store the stream as audit logs into an s3 bucket.

I then query the s3 bucket from Amazon Athena.

Everything seems to be working, but the userIdentity property is always empty (null) which seems pointless to me to have an audit if I cannot capture who did the transaction. Is this property only populated when a record is deleted from DynamoDB and TTL is enabled?

Questions:

1. How do I capture the user id / name of the user responsible for adding, updating, or deleting a record via the application or directly via DynamoDB in AWS console?
2. (Less important question) How do I format the stream before it hits the s3 bucket so I can include the record id being updated?

Also please note that I have a lambda function that I use from the Delivery Stream that simply adds new line to each stream as a delimeter. If I wanted to do more processing/formatting to the stream, should I be executing this lambda when the stream hits the DeliveryStream? Or should I be executing this as a trigger in the DynamoDB table itself before it hits the DeliveryStream?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not include the user details in the Data Stream. This needs to be implemented by the application, then you can get the values from the newImage if provided by the stream.